# How many different 3-letter words (real or imaginary) can be made from BEAUTIFUL?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

The answer is 8P3 + 7(3) = 357 according to the solutions given by my professor. I don't understand why you add the 7(3) or if this is even the right solution.

Comment: If no letter occured twice it would be a straightforward problem with permutations, but there is one letter occuring twice: $U$. Maybe has something to do with it?

Comment: yes it does have something to do with the U but I don't understand how to come to the conclusion that you must add 7(3)

Comment: That's what I hoped to help you learn investigate, but someone was really fast.

Answer (score 2):

There are $9$ letters in the word which $2$ of them are the same letter u.
We want to form $3$-letter words out of these $9$ letters. There are two possibilities:

1. Letter u can only be used once; or
2. Letter u can be used twice

If the letter u can be used only once, then for the first letter we have $8$ choices, for the second letter we have $7$ choices and for the last letter we have $6$ choices; that is

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
8&7&6\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
So the total number of possible words would be $8\times7\times 6=336$.

If the letter u can be repeated twice, then we would have three different arrangements

$$
\begin{align*}
&\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
u&u&7\\ \hline
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
u&7&u\\ \hline
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
7&u&u\\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{align*}
$$
So we would have $1\times1\times7\times3=21$ possible three-letter words.

Thus, the total number of possible three-letter words is $336+21=357$.

Comment: In your first case, the letter u can be used at most once.

Answer (score 1):

8P3 refers to when the word you formed contains at most one 'U'. Then you choose and permute 3 letters out of 8 distinct letters.

The second term 7(3) refers when the word you formed contains 2 U's. In this case you only need to fill in the third gap with any of the remaining 7 letters. Multiply by 3 because there are 3!/2! = 3 ways of arranging the letters.

Answer (score 1):

8P3 for 3 letters word containing only 1 time u.

For 3 letters word containing u twice we have remaining 7 letters after picking u twice. So we have 7 options.

But the letter we picked from remaining 7 letters. We can place it on any of the 3 positions.

So we have 7(3).